# Code throws segmentation fault

Tags: c++, list

I've tried to help a friend with a list code in c++. I've wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct list* createlist(FILE *m);
struct list
{
    char *data;
    struct list *next;
}list;

main()
{

    char a[100], ch;
    struct list* obj;
    cout<<"Enter the name of the file for obtaining input.."<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    FILE *in;

    in=fopen(a,"r");
    if(in!=NULL)
    {

        ch=fgetc(in);
        if(ch=='1')
        obj=createlist(in);
        fclose(in);
    }
    return 0;
}

struct list* createlist(FILE *m)
{
    cout<<"Entered createlist function..!"<<endl;
    char *tempStr = (char *)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    struct list *curr, *head = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    curr = head;
    curr->data = tempStr;
    char c;
    int i=0;
    curr=NULL;
     while(EOF!=(c=fgetc(m)))
        {
            if((c==' ') || (c=='\0') || i == 29)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                tempStr[i]='\0';
                i=0;
                struct list *temp = curr;
                curr = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
                temp->next = curr;
                tempStr = (char *)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
                curr->data = tempStr;
                continue;
            }

            tempStr[i]=c;
            i++;
        }
    return head;
}
```

But the code throw exception. I tried to understand what went wrong and change the code for 2-3 hours, and could not understand. I'm allocating space for the list item, but when I try to assign value to `next` at the line

```
temp->next = curr;
```

I get segmentation fault.

At the end I've managed to solve it by taking some code from the net instead of mine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct list* createlist(FILE *m);
struct list
{
    char *data;
    struct list *next;
}list;

main()
{

    char a[100], ch;
    struct list* obj;
    cout<<"Enter the name of the file for obtaining input.."<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    FILE *in;

    in=fopen(a,"r");
    if(in!=NULL)
    {

        ch=fgetc(in);
        if(ch=='1')
        obj=createlist(in);
        fclose(in);
    }
    return 0;
}

struct list* createlist(FILE *m)
{
    cout<<"Entered createlist function..!"<<endl;
    char *tempStr = (char *)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    struct list *curr, *head = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    curr = head;
    curr->data = tempStr;
    char c;
    int i=0;
    curr=NULL;
    while(EOF!=(c=fgetc(m)))
        {
            if((c==' ') || (c=='\0') || i == 29)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                tempStr[i]='\0';
                i=0;
                struct list *temp = curr;
                curr = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
                temp->next = curr;
                tempStr = (char *)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
                curr->data = tempStr;
                continue;
            }

            tempStr[i]=c;
            i++;
        }
    return head;
}
```

But I still don't know what went wrong in my code. Can anyone help me understand so I won't repeat my mistake in the future?

Comment: Unless you are trying to learn, you should be using the list that already exists in standard library. If you are trying to learn, I'd recommend trying to learn implementing one similarly generic as the standard one is.

Comment: Please decide whether you want to use C or C++. You are writing C with a tiny bit of C++ syntax. So you won't know C (you have syntax that is not C) and you won't know proper modern C++ style either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the you do

```
curr=NULL;
```

just before he while loop

Answer (score 4):

The two versions are identical as far as I can see, but the error is easy to tell. Here's your code with some comments

```
// at this point curr is NULL (see start of while loop)

struct list *temp = curr;
// so now temp is NULL

curr = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
// now curr is pointing at some memory, but temp is still NULL

temp->next = curr;
// temp is NULL so this crashes
```

Like everyone else I think if you remove `curr = NULL;` you'll be closer.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'temp' is NULL:

```
curr=NULL;
```

Afterwards:

```
struct list *temp = curr;
```

And finally:

```
temp->next = curr;
```

You are trying to use structure pointer that has a NULL value.

I know this is not going to help you much, but I see several other problems with the code and it's not easy to read.

Since you marked this C++, did you considet using one of the std containers? Like std::list ?

Answer (score 3):

Before the while loop, you are assigning NULL into curr

```
curr=NULL;
```

Then, you are assigning curr to temp

```
struct list *temp = curr;
```

Then when you do

```
temp->next = curr;
```

you get a segmentation fault because NULL does not have a next pointer.

If you remove `curr=NULL;`, you should be ok.